# 'NoneType' object is not iterable 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

On anaconda i'm not getting any errors while running my code but in IDLE i'm getting the following error

```
player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

my code is

```
# THE FUNCTION
def player_input():
    marker = ''

    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = input('Player 1: Do you want to be X or O? ').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        return ('O', 'X')

while True:        
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
    turn = choose_first()
    print(turn + ' will go first.')

    play_game = input('Are you ready to play? Enter Yes or No.')

    if play_game.lower()[0] == 'y':
        game_on = True
    else:
        game_on = False
```

Comment: What does `player_input()` return ?

Comment: it returns a Tuple

Comment: Apparently it doesn't though. Can you show the code for the function?

Comment: i have posted the code for the function. The problem is this entire code works fine on anaconda but not on IDLE.  I have to submit this project in IDLE format

Comment: The function you posted must not be getting called, it must be getting redefined somewhere, or if it's imported, maybe it's importing a file with a different `player_input`